# Tagging images in S3 bucket with labels from Rekognition AI Service - boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to use AWS Rekognition to identify labels for images that I have stored in an S3 bucket, and subsequently apply those labels to the image file as tags so they're searchable.  I have most of the code working except for the actual tagging process itself.  Here is the code that I have:

```py
import boto3
import botocore
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
photo = ''
bucket_name = 'bluemonkeyimages'
client = boto3.client('rekognition')

def create_tagset(photo):
    response = client.detect_labels(
        Image={
            'S3Object': {
                'Bucket': bucket_name,
                'Name': photo
            },
        },
    )
    tag_list = []
    for t in response['Labels']:
        tag_list.append({'Key': t['Name'],
                        'Value': 'True'})
    print(tag_list)
    try:
        s3.put_object_tagging(
            Bucket=bucket_name,
            Key=photo,
            Tagging={
                'Tagset': tag_list
            }
        )
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as error:
        print(f"could not apply labels to {photo}")
        raise error

    except botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError as error:
        raise ValueError(
            'The parameters you provided are incorrect: {}'.format(error))
s3response = s3.list_objects_v2(
    Bucket=bucket_name
)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    for key in s3response['Contents']:
        create_tagset(key['Key'])
```

That causes this error from the except statements:

```sh
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Missing required parameter in Tagging: "TagSet"
Unknown parameter in Tagging: "Tagset", must be one of: TagSet

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\tagset.py", line 75, in <module>
    create_tagset(key['Key'])
  File ".\tagset.py", line 64, in create_tagset
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The parameters you provided are incorrect: Parameter validation failed:
Missing required parameter in Tagging: "TagSet"
Unknown parameter in Tagging: "Tagset", must be one of: TagSet
```

I am passing in the `'Tagset'` Key and then the dictionary that is created inside of `tag_list`.  Here is an example of the output from the print(tag_list) statement.  It appears to be the correct format going off of the [boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object_tagging) for `put_object_tagging`.

```py
[{'Key': 'Ape', 'Value': 'True'}, {'Key': 'Animal', 'Value': 'True'}, {'Key': 'Mammal', 'Value': 'True'}, {'Key': 'Wildlife', 'Value': 'True'}, {'Key': 'Helmet', 'Value': 'True'}, {'Key': 'Apparel', 'Value': 'True'}, {'Key': 'Clothing', 'Value': 'True'}, {'Key': 'Sports', 'Value': 'True'}, {'Key': 'Football', 'Value': 'True'}, {'Key': 'Team', 'Value': 'True'}, {'Key': 'Soccer Ball', 'Value': 'True'}, {'Key': 'Team Sport', 'Value': 'True'}, {'Key': 'Ball', 'Value': 'True'}, {'Key': 'Soccer', 'Value': 'True'}, {'Key': 'Sport', 'Value': 'True'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object_tagging), it should be `TagSet`, not `Tagset`:

```
Tagging={
    'TagSet': [
        {
            'Key': 'string',
            'Value': 'string'
        },
    ]
}
```

And you have:

```
Tagging={
     'Tagset': tag_list
}
```

Comment: This fixed it. I must have mistyped after I deleted it or something because that's the exact code I copied for boilerplate. Thank you!

Comment: @hashd No problem. Glad I could help.